# Issues with CMS_Encrypt using Open SSL on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, openssl, x509

I'm trying to use OpenSSL's CMS_encrypt method but am getting a crash

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xaa0003f4aa0203fe)

According to the [OpenSSL docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/CMS_encrypt.html):

```
 #include <openssl/cms.h>

 CMS_ContentInfo *CMS_encrypt(STACK_OF(X509) *certs, BIO *in,
                              const EVP_CIPHER *cipher, unsigned int flags);
```

> CMS_encrypt() creates and returns a CMS EnvelopedData structure. certs is a list of recipient certificates. in is the content to be encrypted. cipher is the symmetric cipher to use. flags is an optional set of flags.

I've double checked that the data I'm placing in `dataToEncrpytBIO` is actually getting written correctly to the BIO.

I've tried using various ciphers and flags, and no combination seems to work, so I've kept it as `CMS_Text` for now. (Passing in 0 fails too)

Whats interesting is that it is crashing. That tells me one of my inputs must be invlalid. According to the docs, if it fails to encrypt its supposed to return `NULL`. If it succeeds it should return a `CMS_ContentInfo`

> CMS_encrypt() returns either a CMS_ContentInfo structure or NULL if an error occurred. The error can be obtained from ERR_get_error(3).

I'm guessing that something is wrong with my certificate stack. Although it succeeds to create, and when I look at the stack it says I have 1 certificate on it, I think there is additional code that might be needed around the recipient info, or perhaps the stack is wrong? I'm not sure. I'd love any feedback. Thank you.

```
func cmsEncryptionTest(){
    //Set Algorithms
    addAlgorithms()    

    //Prepare data to encrypt
    let testEncryptionString = "String to Encrypt"
    let testEncryptionData = testEncryptionString.data(using: .utf8)!

    let dataToEncryptBIO = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())

    BIO_write(dataToEncryptBIO, (testEncryptionData as NSData).bytes, Int32(testEncryptionData.count))

    //Prepare Certificate Stack
    let deviceCert = "MIIDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX="

    guard let base64Data = Data(base64Encoded: deviceCert, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters) else {
        throw TestError.failedToDecodeBase64
    }

    let certBIO = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())

    BIO_write(certBIO, (base64Data as NSData).bytes, Int32(base64Data.count))

    guard let x509Cert: UnsafeMutablePointer<X509> = d2i_X509_bio(certBIO, nil) else{
        throw TestError.failedToLoadCertificate
    }

    let certStack = generateX509Stack(x509Cert.pointee)


    //Perform Encryption
    var flags:UInt32 = UInt32(CMS_TEXT)

    //Crashes
    let cms = CMS_encrypt(certs, dataToEncrypt, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), flags)

    ....

}

//Objective-C Helper Method to put a cert on an x509Stack
struct stack_st_X509 * generateX509Stack(X509 cert){

    struct stack_st_X509 sk = *sk_X509_new_null();

    sk_X509_push(&sk, &cert);

    return &sk;
}

//Objective-C Helper Method to add algorithms 
void addAlgorithms(){
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCM is not supported for CMS enveloped data.  Use something like EVP_aes_256_cbc() instead.

UPDATE:

I got the "quote" from a openssl maintainer.  I couldn't find a "clear" list of supported ciphers.

If you look at the CMS help [page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/cms.html) you see:

> See enc(1) for a list of ciphers supported by your version of OpenSSL.

If you look at the linked [enc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html) page you see:

> The enc program does not support authenticated encryption modes like
>   CCM and GCM, and will not support such modes in the future.

Which I beleave applies to CMS as well as it's using the same encryption routines within CMS.

You can also see the "supported" list on the enc page as well.

In trying to repro your example above in C against the openssl lirary directly, it worked for me once I switched the cipher.  So I can only assume your problem is elsewhere.

My repro example of your code that works (i.e. it encrypts and decrypts fine):

```
bool CMS_encrypt_data()
{
    auto const encrypt_certificate_stack = make_handle(sk_X509_new_null(), [](auto handle){ sk_X509_pop_free(handle, X509_free); });
    if(!encrypt_certificate_stack) return false;

    auto file = make_handle(BIO_new_file("alice.pem", "r"), BIO_free);
    auto cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(file.get(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if(!cert) return false;
    sk_X509_push(encrypt_certificate_stack.get(), cert);

    /*
    auto const in = make_handle(BIO_new_file(R"(C:\work\testcert\secret.txt)", "rb"), BIO_free);
    if(!in) return false;
    */

    auto const in = make_handle(BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()), BIO_free);
    if(!in) return false;

    auto const data = "this is a secret"s;
    if(BIO_write(in.get(), data.c_str(), data.size()) <= 0) return false;

    auto const flags = 0;
    auto const content_info = make_handle(CMS_encrypt(encrypt_certificate_stack.get(), in.get(), EVP_aes_256_cbc(), flags), CMS_ContentInfo_free);
    if(!content_info) return false;

    auto const outfile = make_handle(BIO_new_file("secret.out", "w"), BIO_free);
    if(!outfile) return false;
    if(PEM_write_bio_CMS_stream(outfile.get(), content_info.get(), in.get(), flags) == 0) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error regardless of the cypher. On a separate note. How do I now which cyphers are supported by CMS?

Answer (score 1):

Shane's answer is correct in the cipher was not supported, but that wouldn't have caused a crash. The crash was caused by a bug with the pointers in my cert stack. The code below worked for generating my stack

```
+ (nullable struct stack_st_X509 *) generateX509Stack: (nonnull X509 *) cert{

    struct stack_st_X509 *sk = sk_X509_new_null();

    int result = sk_X509_push(sk, cert);

    return sk;
}
```

I was returning the memory reference of the stack of certs `&sk`, and was creating it on the stack instead of as a pointer to another piece of memory. After exiting the method it would later get stomped on by something else in the future. Which is why the encryption was failing for me.

I also changed the cipher to `EVP_aes_256_cbc()`. I tried using the gym and it failed to encrypt, but followed the OpenSSL docs, and just returned a null object.